# Why does COBOL have both `SECTION` and `PARAGRAPH`?

Tags: language-design, cobol

Why does COBOL have both `SECTION` and `PARAGRAPH`?

Can anybody explain why the designers of COBOL created both `SECTION`s and `PARAGRAPH`s? These have been around since the initial release of COBOL so I suspect the real reason for their existence has long since gone away (similar to things like `NEXT SENTENCE` which are still in the language specification for backward compatibility but no longer required since the introduction of explicit scope terminators).

My guess is that `SECTION` may have been introduced to support program overlays. `SECTION` has an optional PRIORITY number associated with it to identify the program overlay it is part of. However, most modern implementations of COBOL ignore or have dropped PRIORITY numbers (and overlays).

Currently, I see that `SECTION`s are still required in the `DECLARATIVE` part of the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`, but can find no justification for this. I see no semantic difference between `SECTION` and `PARAGRAPH` other than `PARAGRAPH` is subordinate to `SECTION`.

Some COBOL shops ban the use of `SECTION` in favour of `PARAGRAPH` (seems common in North America). Others ban `PARAGRAPH` in favour of `SECTION` (seems common in Europe). Still others have guidelines as to when each is appropriate. All of this seems highly arbitrary to me - which begs the question: Why were they put into the language specification in the first place? And, do they have any relevance today?

If you answer this question, it would be great if you could also point to a reference to support your answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No references on this, since I heard it passed on to me from one of the old timers in my shop but...

In the old COBOL compilers, at least for IBM and Unisys, sections were able to be loaded into memory one at a time. Back in the good old days when memory was scarce, a program that was too large to be loaded into memory all at once was able to be modularized for memory usage using sections. Having both sections and paragraphs allowed the programmer to decide which code parts were loaded into memory together if they couldn't all be loaded at once - you'd want two parts of the same perform loop loaded together for efficiency's sake. Nowadays it's more or less moot.

My shop uses paragraphs only, prohibits GOTO and requires exit paragraphs, so all our PERFORMS are PERFORM 100-PARAGRAPH THRU 100-EXIT or something similar - which seems to make the paragraphs more like sections to me. But I don't think that there's really much of a difference now.

Comment: Bah, I see that colemanj had the same answer as me. I just scrolled down past the first answer entry. I can't comment on others' answers yet so I'll leave this as a slightly expanded explanation of what colemanj said.

Comment: I think you and colemanj have the correct answer, but 
your answer is more articulate. Program segmentation was the "state or the art"
mechanism for managing "large" programs in a small address space. Fortunately
virtual memory made this function obsolete (I have been around long enough to
have experienced the "joy" of writing segmented programs). All I see remaining
is a possible "name spacing" use and an unexplained requirement that Declaratives
reference Sections as opposed to Paragraphs (as pointed out by Tim Sylvester).

Answer (score 6):

I learned COBOL around 1978, on an ICL 2903. I have a vague memory that the SECTION headers could be assigned a number range, which meant that those SECTION headers could be swapped in and out of memory, when the program was too large for memory.

Comment: Yup, those were PRIORITY numbers, and I bet you could give me a bunch of horror stories on having to use them too. I believe a program could get into real trouble if you ever let one independent segment (priority number >= 50) referenced another independent segment. Fortunately, those days are pretty much behind us now...

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but the OP requested about documentation on the original justification of the use of SECTION as well as PARAGRAPH in COBOL.

You can't get much more "original" than the CODASYL Journal documentation.

in section 8 of the Journal's specification for the language,

> "COBOL segmentation is a facility that provides a means by which the
>   user may communicate with the compiler to specify object program
>   overlay requirements"

( page 331, section 8.1 "Segmentation - General Description")

> "Although it is not mandatory, the Procedure Division for a source
>   program is usually written as a consecutive group of sections, each of
>   which is composed of a series of closely related operations that are
>   designed to collectively perform a particular function. However s when
>   segmentation is used, the entire Procedure Division must be in
>   sections. In addition, each section must be classified as belonging
>   either to the fixed portion or to one of the independent segments of
>   the object program. Segmentation in no way affects the need for
>   qualification of procedure-names to insure uniqueness."

(p 331, section 8.1.2.1 "Program Segments")

In her book on comparative programming languages ("Programming Languages: History and Fundamentals", 1969) Jean Sammet (who sat on the CODASYL committee, representing Sylvania Electric) states:

> ".. The storage allocation is handled automatically by the compiler. 
>   The prime unit for allocating executable code is a group of sections
>   called a *segment.*  The programmer combines sections be specifying a
>   priority number with each section's name. ... The compiler is required
>   to see that the proper control transfers are provided so that control
>   among segments which are not stored simultaneously can take place.
>   ..."

(p 369 - 371 V.3 COBOL)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simplest of the reasons is that SECTION s provide you the "modularity" -- just as functions in C -- a necessity in the "structured" programs. You would notice that code written using SECTIONs appears far more readable than the code written just in paragraphs, for every section has to have an "EXIT" -- a sole and very explicit exit point from a SECTION (exit point of a paragrpah is far more vague and implicit, i.e. until a new paragraph declaration is found). Consider this example and you may be tempted to use sections in your code:

```
*==================
 MAINLINE SECTION.
*==================
     PERFORM SEC-A
     PERFORM SEC-B
     PERFORM SEC-C
     GOBACK.
*==================
 MAINLINE-EXIT.
*==================
    EXIT.

*==================
 SEC-A SECTION.
*==================

.....
.....
.....
.....

    IF <cond>
       go to A-EXIT
    end-if

..... 
.....
.....
.....

.

*==================
 A-EXIT.
*==================
    EXIT.
```

Don't think you would have this sort of a privlege when writing your codes in paragraphs. You may have had to write a huge ELSE statement to cover up the statements you didn't want to execute when a certain condition is reached (consider that set of statements to be running across 2-3 pages... a further set of IF / ELSE would cramp you up for indentation). Of course, you'll have to use "GO TO" to achieve this, but you can always direct your professionals not to use GO TOs except while Exiting, which is a fair deal, I think.

So, whilst I also agree that anything that can be written using SECTIONs can also be written using paragraphs (with little or no tweaks), my personal choice would be to go for an implementation that can make the job of my developers a little easier in future!

Comment: +1 for the interesting feedback. You describe a particular coding style using SECTION/PARAGRAPH rather
than identify the language design criteria that led to inclusion of both SECTION and PARAGRAPH
into the COBOL language specification. Note in your example if SECTION headers are dropped,
making them into PARAGRAPHs, and `PERFORM SEC-A` is replaced by `PERFORM SEC-A THRU A-EXIT` etc. 
you have a functionally equivalent program using only PARAGRAPH.
BTW Place `MAINLINE-EXIT` before `GOBACK` otherwise `GO TO MAINLINE-EXIT` will most
certainly lead to trouble!

Comment: Those who resort to "GO TO" as a "first response" to a program design flaw :-) tend to imagine that those who don't must code deeply-nested IF/EVALUATE instead.
This need not be true, although it does happen.

Answer (score 2):

Cobol was developed in the mid-50's. As the full name alludes, it was developed for business programming, as being a language more relevant for business purposes than the existing "scientific" or "technical" languages (there were very few "languages" anyway, and "machine code" (specific, of course, to a particular architechture (I nearly said "specific chip", before thinking of vacuum tubes)) which may have to be set through physical switches/dials on some machines) and if lucky with an "Assembler". Cobol was very advanced for its day, for its purpose.

The intention was for programs written in Cobol to be much more like English-language than just a set of "codes" which mean something to the initiated.

If you look at some of the nomenclature relating to the language - paragraph, sentence, verb, clause - it is deliberately following the patterns ascribed to the English language.

SECTION doesn't quite fit into this, until you relate things to a formal business document.

Both SECTIONs and paragraphs also appear outside the PROCEDURE DIVISION. As in written English, paragraphs can exist on their own, or can be a part of a SECTION.

SECTIONs may have a priority-number which relates to the "segmentation feature". This used to include "overlaying" of SECTIONs to afford a primitive level of memory management. This is a "computing featuer" rather than an English-language one :-) The "segmentation feature" does have something of a remaining affect, but I've never seen it actually used.

Without DECLARATIVES (which I don't use, and have just noticed the manual to be unclear upon) then it is "choice" as to whether SECTIONs or paragraphs are used for PERFORM.

If GO TO is used, rationally, "equivalence" can be achieved with PERFORM ... TRHU .... If not, and there is not gratuitous use of PERFORM ... THRU ..., then there is equivalence already.

Comparisons to "structured" code and modern languages are "reading history backwards" or just outlining a particular "practice". From the reputation attained by "spaghetti code" and ALTER ... TO PROCEED TO ... it may well be that for 20 years it was "common" to not do much with PERFORM unless you needed the "memory management", but I have no references or knowledge to back this up.

SECTIONs allow duplicate paragraph-names, otherwise paragraph-names must be unique.

I can't put a specific finger on one over the other all the time.

If using GO TO, I'd use SECTIONs. If not, paragraphs. With DECLARATIVES I'd use SECTIONs. If using SECTIONs I'd start PROCEDURE DIVISION with a SECTION to avoid a diagnostic message.

Local standards may dictate, but not necessarily on a "modern" (or even "rational") basis. Much is "known" but actually misunderstood about SECTIONs and paragraphs, in my experience.

For performance (where masses of data is being processed, and I mean masses) then a PERFORM of one SECTION rather than multiple individual paragraphs would see improvements. The effect would be the same with PERFORM ... THRU ..., but I prefer not to recommend it.
GO TO outside the range of a PERFORM is 1) bad 2) can lose out on "optimization". Shouldn't be a problem *except" when GO TO abend/exception and not expecting any logical return. If the use of this is felt to be necessarily "immediately", then it is better done with a PERFORM despite the "counter-intuitive" aspect (so document it).

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, paragraph names must be unique unless they are in separate sections, so sections allow for "namespacing" of paragraphs.

If I recall correctly, the only reason you *must* use a `SECTION` is for `DECLARATIVES`.  Aside from that they are optional and primarily useful for grouping paragraphs.  I think it's common (relatively speaking, anyway) to require that `PERFORM` be used on paragraphs only when they are in the same section.

Comment: I had forgotten about the "namespacing" feature that `SECTION`s provide over `PARAGRAPH`s, but was that the justification the language designers used when coming up with these constructs?

J.Sammet wrote an interesting article on the Early History of COBOL some time ago where some insight was given into why certain language features are the way they are but provided no insight as to why both `SECTION` and `PARAGRAPH` were incorporated. I just don't get it - but these people were not dummies so I imagine there must have been good reasons for having them. Thanks, Neal

Answer (score 1):

A section can have several paragraphs in it.  When you PERFORM a section, it executes **all** the paragraphs in the section.  Within the section you can use PERFORM or GOTO to branch to the paragraphs within the section.

Comment: Hence the EXIT statement as a target for GO TOs. Today, EXIT is just a place to "hang" a paragraph name. I think some early compilers required EXIT to be the only statement in the last paragraph of a performed range of SECTIONs/PARAGRAPHs. It  was required to generate code implementing the return from a PERFORMed range.

Since PARAGRAPH is subordinate to SECTION, one can expect that PERFORMing a SECTION will execute all contained paragraphs.  A range of paragraphs may be executed using `PERFORM para-1 THROUGH para-n` so the same functionality may be achieved using paragraphs only.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the best I can to answer this. If your only coding exposure is x86 or ARM then you will have significant difficulty. Yes those chips sell a lot but that doesn't mean they are good, just cheap enough people don't mind throwing them away.

Much of this information can be found in "[The Minimum You Need to Know to Be an OpenVMS Application Developer](https://theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/app_book.html)." You will find it is one of the scant few titles on [Dr. Dobb's recommended reading list for all developers](https://www.drdobbs.com/tools/developers-reading-list/232500396?pgno=6). Yes, I wrote it. It is also the book recommended by HP OpenVMS Engineering group for developers looking to learn the platform.

My COBOL on that platform mostly happened during the 1980s when it was VAX/VMS. Then it became OpenVMS; Alpha/OpenVMS; Itanium/OpenVMS; and soon to be x86/OpenVMS. On a real computer with a real operating system, sections have meaning. Every section created a PSECT. In linker terms that was short for Program SECtion. Based on what the section was, various load attributes were set. Each PSECT would be loaded into one or more 512 Byte memory pages. Memory pages were designed to be the exact same size as a disk block. VMS stood for Virtual Memory System. IBM had several of their own operating systems which, under the hood were different, but they too were true virtual memory systems. This wasn't "overlay linking." That's an x86 term and came about due to severe architectural flaws.Read up on Compact, Small, Medium, and Large "memory models" from the 286 days on forward. Also read up on EMS and XMS memory paging. Oiy was THAT fun!

Here is one of the numerous programs found in that book.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
```

PROGRAM-ID.     COB_ZILL_DUE_REPORT_SUB.
AUTHOR.         Roland Hughes.
DATE-WRITTEN.   2005-02-08.
DATE-COMPILED.  TODAY.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

FILE-CONTROL.

```
SELECT DRAW-STATS
    ASSIGN TO 'DRAWING_STATS'
    ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
    ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
    RECORD KEY IS ELM_NO IN DSTATS-REC
    LOCK MODE IS AUTOMATIC
    FILE STATUS IS D-STAT.

SELECT MEGA-STATS
    ASSIGN TO 'MEGA_STATS'
    ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
    ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
    RECORD KEY IS ELM_NO IN MSTATS-REC
    LOCK MODE IS AUTOMATIC
    FILE STATUS IS M-STAT.

SELECT SORT-FILE ASSIGN TO 'TMP.SRT'.

SELECT SORTED-FILE ASSIGN TO DISK.

SELECT RPT-FILE ASSIGN TO 'ZILL_DUE.RPT'.
```

DATA DIVISION.

FILE SECTION.

FD  DRAW-STATS
    IS GLOBAL
    LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.

```
COPY 'CDD_RECORDS.ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD' FROM DICTIONARY
    REPLACING ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD BY DSTATS-REC.
```

FD  MEGA-STATS
    IS GLOBAL
    LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.

```
COPY 'CDD_RECORDS.ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD' FROM DICTIONARY
    REPLACING ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD BY MSTATS-REC.
```

FD  RPT-FILE
    LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED.

```
01 RPT-DTL                         PIC X(80).
```

SD  SORT-FILE.

```
COPY 'CDD_RECORDS.ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD' FROM DICTIONARY
    REPLACING ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD BY SORT-REC.
```

FD  SORTED-FILE
    VALUE OF ID IS SORTED-FILE-NAME.

```
COPY 'CDD_RECORDS.ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD' FROM DICTIONARY
    REPLACING ZILLIONARE_STATS_RECORD BY SORTED-REC.
```

---

- Data declarations

  ---

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 CONSTANTS.
       05 SORT-FILE-NAME        PIC X(7) VALUE 'TMP.SRT'.
       05 SORTED-FILE-NAME      PIC X(8) VALUE 'STAT.SRT'.

```
01 STATUS-VARIABLES.
   05 M-STAT                PIC X(2).
   05 D-STAT                PIC X(2).
   05 EOF-FLAG              PIC X.
      88 IT-IS-END-OF-FILE VALUE 'Y'.

01 STUFF.
   05 TODAYS-DATE.
      10 TODAY_YYYY         PIC X(4).
      10 TODAY_MM           PIC X(2).
      10 TODAY_DD           PIC X(2).

   05 TODAYS-DATE-FORMATTED.
      10 FMT_MM             PIC Z9.
      10 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '/'.
      10 FMT_DD             PIC 99.
      10 FILLER             PIC X VALUE '/'.
      10 FMT_YYYY           PIC 9(4).

   05 FLT-1                 COMP-2.
   05 WORK-STR              PIC X(65).

01 REPORT-DETAIL.
   05 ELM-NO-DTL            PIC Z9.
   05 FILLER                PIC X(3).
   05 HIT-COUNT-DTL         PIC ZZZ9.
   05 FILLER                PIC X(3).
   05 SINCE-LAST-DTL        PIC ZZZ9.
   05 FILLER                PIC X(5).
   05 PCT-HITS-DTL          PIC Z9.999.
   05 FILLER                PIC X(4).
   05 AVE-BTWN-DTL          PIC ZZ9.999.

01 REPORT-HDR1.
   05 THE-DATE              PIC X(12).
   05 FILLER                PIC X(20).
   05 PAGE-TITLE            PIC X(17).

01 REPORT-HDR2.
   05 FILLER                PIC X(33).
   05 GROUP-TITLE           PIC X(20).

01 REPORT-HDR3.
   05 HDR3-TXT              PIC X(40) VALUE
        'No   Hits   Since   Pct_hits   Ave_btwn'.

01 REPORT-HDR4.
   05 HDR4-TXT              PIC X(40) VALUE
        '--   ----   -----   --------   --------'.
```

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

A000-MAIN.

```
PERFORM B000-HSK.

SORT SORT-FILE
    ON DESCENDING KEY SINCE_LAST IN SORT-REC
    INPUT PROCEDURE IS S000-DSTAT-INPUT
    GIVING SORTED-FILE.

PERFORM B010-REPORT-DRAWING-NUMBERS.


STRING SORT-FILE-NAME, ';*' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO WORK-STR.
CALL 'LIB$DELETE_FILE' USING BY DESCRIPTOR WORK-STR.

STRING SORTED-FILE-NAME, ';*' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO WORK-STR.
CALL 'LIB$DELETE_FILE' USING BY DESCRIPTOR WORK-STR.
```

*
*   Set up for second part of report
*
    MOVE SPACES TO RPT-DTL.
    WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING PAGE.

```
MOVE SPACES TO EOF-FLAG.
MOVE ' Mega Drawing Numbers' TO GROUP-TITLE.

SORT SORT-FILE
    ON DESCENDING KEY SINCE_LAST IN SORT-REC
    INPUT PROCEDURE IS S001-MSTAT-INPUT
    GIVING SORTED-FILE.


PERFORM B010-REPORT-DRAWING-NUMBERS.


STRING SORT-FILE-NAME, ';*' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO WORK-STR.
CALL 'LIB$DELETE_FILE' USING BY DESCRIPTOR WORK-STR.

STRING SORTED-FILE-NAME, ';*' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO WORK-STR.
CALL 'LIB$DELETE_FILE' USING BY DESCRIPTOR WORK-STR.


CLOSE RPT-FILE.

CALL 'LIB$SPAWN' USING BY DESCRIPTOR 'EDIT/READ ZILL_DUE.RPT'.

EXIT PROGRAM.
```

---

- Paragraph to initialize our data and files.

  ---

B000-HSK.
    CALL 'COB_FILL_IN_LOGICALS'.

```
MOVE SPACES TO STATUS-VARIABLES.

ACCEPT TODAYS-DATE FROM DATE YYYYMMDD.

MOVE TODAY_YYYY TO FMT_YYYY.
MOVE TODAY_DD   TO FMT_DD.
MOVE TODAY_MM   TO FMT_MM.


OPEN OUTPUT RPT-FILE.


MOVE SPACES TO REPORT-HDR1.
MOVE TODAYS-DATE-FORMATTED TO THE-DATE.
MOVE 'Due Number Report' to PAGE-TITLE.

MOVE SPACES TO REPORT-HDR2.
MOVE 'Drawing Numbers' TO GROUP-TITLE.
```

---

- Paragraph to process the sorted selection file and
- create the portion of the report relating to drawing
- numbers.

  ---

B010-REPORT-DRAWING-NUMBERS.

```
MOVE SPACES TO EOF-FLAG.

OPEN INPUT SORTED-FILE.

READ SORTED-FILE
    AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE.

PERFORM C010-DRAWING-HEADINGS.

PERFORM UNTIL IT-IS-END-OF-FILE
    MOVE SPACES TO REPORT-DETAIL
    MOVE ELM_NO IN SORTED-REC TO ELM-NO-DTL
    MOVE HIT_COUNT IN SORTED-REC TO HIT-COUNT-DTL
    MOVE SINCE_LAST IN SORTED-REC TO SINCE-LAST-DTL
    MOVE PCT_HITS IN SORTED-REC TO PCT-HITS-DTL
    MOVE AVE_BTWN IN SORTED-REC TO AVE-BTWN-DTL
    MOVE REPORT-DETAIL TO RPT-DTL
    WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING 1 LINE
    READ SORTED-FILE
        AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE
    END-READ
END-PERFORM.

CLOSE SORTED-FILE.
```

---

- Paragraph to print headings for the main drawing numbers
- Which are due.

  ---

C010-DRAWING-HEADINGS.

```
MOVE SPACES TO RPT-DTL.


MOVE REPORT-HDR1 TO RPT-DTL.

WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING 2 LINES.

MOVE SPACES TO RPT-DTL.

MOVE REPORT-HDR2 TO RPT-DTL.

WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING 1 LINE.

MOVE SPACES TO RPT-DTL.
MOVE REPORT-HDR3 TO RPT-DTL.
WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING 1 LINE.

MOVE SPACES TO RPT-DTL.
MOVE REPORT-HDR4 TO RPT-DTL.
WRITE RPT-DTL BEFORE ADVANCING 1 LINE.
```

---

- Paragraph to filter due numbers into sort file.
- Creates a floating point temporary to compare against
- floating point value from input file.  When greater
- record is released to the sort file.

  ---

S000-DSTAT-INPUT.

```
OPEN INPUT DRAW-STATS.

READ DRAW-STATS NEXT
    AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE.

PERFORM UNTIL IT-IS-END-OF-FILE

    MOVE SINCE_LAST IN DSTATS-REC TO FLT-1

    IF FLT-1 >= AVE_BTWN IN DSTATS-REC
        MOVE DSTATS-REC TO SORT-REC
        RELEASE SORT-REC
    END-IF
    READ DRAW-STATS
        AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE
    END-READ
END-PERFORM.

CLOSE DRAW-STATS.
```

---

- Paragraph to filter due numbers into sort file.
- Creates a floating point temporary to compare against
- floating point value from input file.  When greater
- record is released to the sort file.

  ---

S001-MSTAT-INPUT.

```
OPEN INPUT MEGA-STATS.

READ MEGA-STATS NEXT
    AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE.

PERFORM UNTIL IT-IS-END-OF-FILE

    MOVE SINCE_LAST IN MSTATS-REC TO FLT-1

    IF FLT-1 >= AVE_BTWN IN MSTATS-REC
        MOVE MSTATS-REC TO SORT-REC
        RELEASE SORT-REC
    END-IF
    READ MEGA-STATS
        AT END SET IT-IS-END-OF-FILE TO TRUE
    END-READ
END-PERFORM.

CLOSE MEGA-STATS.
```

END PROGRAM COB_ZILL_DUE_REPORT_SUB.

Sorry for the way the "code" feature works in this editor.

Certain sections **have** to exist. Your program cannot do I-O without an INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. This is where you map names to physical storage.

If you have an INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION then you have to have a FILE SECTION. This is where you define the record layout(s) of each named file. LABEL RECORDS are always STANDARD when dealing with disk data files and OMITTED when writing report text files. There are a few other clauses I don't remember. Please note the SD included in all of those FD statements. FD is File Definition and SD is Sort Definition.

If you are going to have any local variables you have to have a WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. You cannot declare variables on the fly, they all have to be declared here. This PSECT gets a DATA segment attribute among other things. If you call some service or something and it has a bad address, attempting to execute code within this PSECT the operating system will shoot your application out of the saddle.

All PSECTs created after PROCEDURE DIVISION are flagged EXEC, write protected. If you try to overwrite anything in here during execution the operating system will shoot your program out of the saddle. Any other program attempting to write here will also be shot out of the saddle.

Scan down to the SORT SORT-FILE in A000-MAIN. The COBOL sort routine is amazing. Notice that I provided an INPUT PROCEDURE and it is a paragraph. On IBM mainframes running ROSCOE back in the day this had to be an INPUT SECTION. They needed different attributes on the PSECT so the system sort routine could read/write.

Here is a snippet from another program in that book.

```
*
```

*   FMS definitions
*
COPY 'COBFDVDEF' OF 'MEGA_TEXT_LIB'.

LINKAGE SECTION.

```
01 FMS-STUFF.
   05 FMSSTATUS                 PIC S9(9) COMP.
   05 RMSSTATUS                 PIC S9(9) COMP.
   05 TCA                       PIC X(12).
   05 WORKSPACE                 PIC X(12).
```

PROCEDURE DIVISION USING FMS-STUFF.

The linkage section creates a PSECT of sharable memory. When you call external routines which return values, they need to be here.You must also grant your PROCEDURE DIVISION access to various things it needs in the linkage section.

As you can see from this snippet later in the code

```
B010-USER-INPUT.

PERFORM C000-FORWARD-LOAD

CALL 'FDV$PUTAL' USING BY DESCRIPTOR SCREEN-REC.

MOVE SPACES TO WORK-STR.

CALL 'FDV$GETAL' USING BY DESCRIPTOR WORK-STR
                       BY REFERENCE TERMINATOR.


EVALUATE TERMINATOR
    WHEN FDV$K_FK_E6    SET LOAD-FORWARD TO TRUE
    WHEN FDV$K_FK_E5    SET LOAD-REVERSE TO TRUE
    WHEN FDV$K_FK_F10   SET WE-ARE-DONE TO TRUE
END-EVALUATE.
```

you can pass any local variable you wish as long as you pass it correctly. It's the writing which needs special PSECT attributes.

It's late and I'm tired but I seem to remember you could could have USING clauses on SECTION declarations in the PROCEDURE DIVISION. The on-line documentation available for COBOL, at least that indexed by GOOGLE really is quite worthless. If you want more detailed information search for a circa 1980s COBOL textbook. It won't have any of the new stuff but it will answer many questions.

Here's a [kind of bad tutorial on COBOL structure](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_program_structure.htm).

Answer (score -1):

We use COBOL **SECTION** coding in all of our 37K MVS batch COBOL programs.  We use this technique to get  much faster run times and significantly reduced CPU overhead.   This COBOL coding technique is very similar to high performance batch assembler.

Call it **High Performance Functionally Structured COBOL** programming

Once a SECTION is defined all PERFORM xxxxx will return at the next coded SECTION not the next paragraph in the SECTION. If paragraphs are coded ahead of the first SECTION then they can be executed normally.  *(But we don't allow this)*

Using a SECTION has higher overhead than when using and **PERFORM** ing only paragraphs - ***U N L E S S*** - you use **GOTO** logic to bypass code that should be conditionally executed.  Our rule is that a **GOTO** can only point to a **Tag-Line** in the same SECTION.  *(a paragraph)* All paragraphs in a SECTION must be a sub function of the SECTION s function.   The **EXIT** instruction is an assembler NOP instruction.  It allow for a **Tag-Line** to be placed before the next SECTION - a fast exit/return.

Executing a **PERFORM** xxxx **THRU** yyyy has more CPU overhead than execution a SECTION without the **GOTO** s.

WARNING:  Executing a PERFORM xxxx **Tag-Line** in a SECTION will fall thru all the code in the SECTION until the next SECTION is encountered.  A **GOTO** **Tag-Line** outside of the current SECTION will fall thru all the code in the new landing SECTION until the next SECTION is encountered. *(But we don't allow this)*

Comment: Interesting... Have *you* done benchmark testing to demonstrate these
performance differences? I was under the impression that the control
mechanism used in IBM compilers was *exactly* the same when PERFORMing SECTIONS and
PARAGRAPHS. The control mechanism used in 
IBM COBOL compilers to implement the return from a 
PERFORM is described in [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=381788.316163)
I would not expect any difference in performing a SECTION or a PARAGRAPH.

Comment: I know this is "old", but...

There are many contradictions and misconceptions here. They may be born of poor wording, but they are there. "Coder beware". The "Warning" in particular does not make sense - the first part is not true, the second part need not be true.

There is only one sense in which PERFORMing a SECTION with multiple paragraphs will be "faster" than PERFORMing the individual paragraphs (outside of a SECTION, it would be absurd to do it if they are *inside* a SECTION):

PERFORM A-SECTION (containing B-PARA and C-PARA)

PERFORM B-PARA
PERFORM C-PARA

The first is less code.

Comment: Speaking as a COBOL compiler writer, this is a load of nonsense. Using a SECTION isn't intrinsically different from using paragraphs. There is no reason to expect it to be faster or slower, whichever you are claiming. I don't know why you use the non-COBOL term 'Tag-Line' when PARAGRAPH already exists. The coding technique you describe has nothing whatsoever to do with 'high performance batch assembler'. Using GOTO to bypass conditional logic is not preferable to using ELSE. EXIT is not an assembler NOP: it is a conditional return. There are no GOTOs in PERFORM xxx THRU yyy. @BillWoodger++