# Program to visualize logic flow

Tags: java, cobol, visualize

I work in an enterprise system and we just received an old COBOL file full of business rules. It's a large collection of IF ELSE statements that assign a value to a variable. Is there a program where I can enter all these IF ELSE logic statements and see the overall flow at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged Java? You could port it to python and use something like Light Table to get the output as you write it. If nothing else, for all intents and purposes, the IF ELSE logic works the same in any language so you can interpret it as-is.

Comment: Can you post the code please?  Are you porting this to Java?

Comment: @TylerHeiks: I don't think he wants to translate COBOL If-Else statemens to Java If-Else statements, but use modern OOP design to rewrite the application (he needs to know things about the domain in order to do so)

Answer (score 1):

I found this using our beloved Google:

http://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html
http://www.aivosto.com/visustin/help/cobol.html
http://www.usflowchart.com/

Also, I suggest you search StackOverflow before asking questions:
[migrate COBOL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597331/migrate-cobol-code)

Answer (score 1):

IBM's Rational Developer for z/OS has a number of helpful things for this -- it will format and indent your source files for easier human understanding; it will provide you with a tree-line outline view; there are some reporting and UML extensions available, though I've never used them with Cobol and I don't know the level of support there.

There are a number of tools that will visualize Cobol code into flow charts or other representations.  Plugging "visualize cobol" into the google will give you a number of other options.